# texture does not apply correctly on several faces

Tags: blender

After rendering a simple object, some faces have a corrupt texture, even all faces should use the same texture.
Did i miss something or does anyone knows a workaround for this?

- Removing Smooth shows the correct texture.
- Similar issue with other textures
- Removing and recreating faces does not solve the problem.

Below a link to the Blender File.

Thank you very much.

[image: Rendered image from Blender with marked issue]

Blender File example:
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=9260E6210D9A2E5B!807&authkey=!AEKG2Qgg1spEHCc

> Edit: Im using Blender 2.68a Windows 64 bits on Win8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the **Mapping** section in the texture settings, change the texture coordinates from **Normal** to **Generated**.